# Why do I need to install Realtek or Intel Graphics Driver software?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

I just installed Windows 8.1 Professional on my Acer Aspire 5738 from Dreamspark. I need to know whether there is any significant improvement in audio or graphics quality when I install Realtek audio driver (since obviously I can play songs without any issues) or Intel Graphics Driver for my laptop. Otherwise I could very well use the extra disk space to store my documents. What would I miss without them?

Comment: If you have audio and video capabilities then the generic Microsoft Audio/Video driver for usage case seems to be all you need.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you specifically mean by 'If you have audio and video capabilities...'? since every system nowadays has the capability to play audio and video out of the box. Why do we specifically need those drivers then?

Comment: Don't these machines come stock with 500GB? I can't imagine these two drivers coming close to using 1GB

Comment: @root Mine has about 280GB. And its all full. And why waste even 1GB for drivers which do not provide any specific improvements?

Comment: I was under the impression that the device was fresh out of the box. Drivers like these are often recommended because they have been tested and are the standard to power audio/video devices. If either of these services fail, the first line of support you'll receive is, "Are you running the recommended drivers?" More than anything, I'm sure they provide a standard of a known working state that is universally run on the device for many users.

Comment: @root So its no use installing them as far as everything is working properly, right?

Comment: @nisargshah95 - Some audio and video devices do not work or work poorly with the generic drivers.  My statement is clear, if the devices are working to your statisification, don't install the specific device drivers.  I can't believe you are that short on space that you can't afford to install the 25MB-100MB to get a possible performance boot or additional features working.  Its entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to install the specific driver software if the generic Microsoft drivers are working to your satisfaction. If you do choose to install them, ensure they are Windows 8 compatible.

*Just be aware some special features or functions which may be specific to the manufacturer's drivers software may not be available to you.*